# How to replace a paragraph with new paragraph

Tags: perl, unix, awk, sed

I have a file which has alot of PIN. The situation is as shown below

```
PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE SIGNAL
```

I want to replace this with

```
PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE POWER
```

such that the signal is changed to power only when PIN ABC is appears in the file. Is it possible to do it with grep or awk.

Comment: If your problem involves _alot of PIN_ your example data should contain at least two of them. Are there some _paragraph_ delimiters in the source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`, rewrite lines starting with `USE` after a line with `PIN ABC`. The final `1` prints the (possibly modified) line.

```
$ awk '/^PIN/{pin=$2} /^USE/&&(pin=="ABC"){$2="POWER"} 1' file
PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE POWER
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP and future visitors guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution. [Code-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/238706)

Comment: @Palec while I agree with that for large/complicated solutions I disagree with that philosophy for trivial code snippets. Current and future readers who don't know what this solution does will get much more out of reading the first chapter of any available awk documentation than me explaining the basics of awk syntax to them and if after reading the documentation they still can't figure it out they can always ask a question.

Comment: Even trivial code snippets can have useful description. Reading the docs when you start learning a new tool is not always the best option. Commented snippets can serve as mini-tutorials and can be much more effective. E.g. in this case, I’d introduce the snippet with: *Using `awk`, rewrite lines starting with `USE` after a line with `PIN ABC`. The final `1` prints the (possibly modified) line.*

Comment: @Palec feel free to edit the answer to add explanatory text if you like but my opinion is and will continue to be that it is useless at best to do so and probably reduces the benefit a newbie could get from it. Also, if I had to explain the basics of awk every time I post an awk answer I just wouldn't contribute any answers. As I said, anyone who doesn't understand it can always ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `awk`

```
awk '/^PIN ABC/ {a=NR} a+2==NR {$2="POWER"} 1' file
PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE POWER
```

---

If number of lines between `PIN` and `USE` is not fixed:

```
awk '/^PIN/ {f=1} f && /^USE/ {$2="POWER";f=0} 1' file
PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE POWER
```

Comment: The second command rewrites `USE` lines in all blocks. I guess there are more blocks starting with `PIN <name>` and ending with `USE POWER` or `USE SIGNAL`.

Comment: @Palec Try `awk '/^PIN ABC/ {f=1} f && /^USE SIGNAL/ {$2="POWER";f=0} 1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your "paragraphs" are separated by blank lines:

```
perl -00 -pe 's/^(PIN ABC.*USE) \w+/$1 POWER/s' <<END
some stuff

PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE SIGNAL

PIN DEF
USE SIGNAL

more stuff
END
```

```
some stuff

PIN ABC
DIRECTION INPUT
USE POWER

PIN DEF
USE SIGNAL

more stuff
```

This uses

- option `-00` to read paragraphs, not lines
- `-p` to loop over the records and implicitly print after modifications
- the `s` modifier to the `s///` command to allow `.` to match newlines

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '1h;1!H;${x;/PIN ABC/ s/USE SIGNAL/USE POWER/g;p;}' YourFile
```

- dont print line unless requested
- load the file in buffer (1st line overwritte, other append)
- at the end

  - if PIN ABC is found, change USE SIGNAL
  - print result

Now, you certainly mean lot of different PIN ABC (not clear between several same ABC or several PIN with different ABC), in this case this script, like this does not suite because it change EVERY USE SIGNAL at first occurence